# Google api php How to edit Google table

Tags: php, google-api

Good afternoon!
I can download files from the disc with a Google api method:

```
function downloadFile($service, $downloadUrl,$client) {

    if ($downloadUrl) {
        $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);

        $SignhttpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
        $httpRequest = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($SignhttpRequest);

        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
            return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
        } else {
            // An error occurred.
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I can not download a file created on the Google Tables. No links in "downloadUrl".
Tell me how you can download and edit the file created on the Google Tables?